# Display full error messages inline with Simple Form 2 and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I would like to display the full error message (with humanized attribute name, that is, not just "can't be blank") with Simple Form 2 and Rails 3. It seems that Simple Form 3 has a `use.full_error` option but this doesn't exist in Simple Form 2 and I can't upgrade at this time because Simple Form 3 requires Rails 4.

What's the most straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can specify the error message that you want to show against each validation line (as shown below).

```
validates_presence_of :title, :message => "Please provide a valid Title"
```

OR

```
validates :title, :presence => {:message => "Please provide a valid Title" }
```

Comment: Yes, but ideally I could find a way to use the existing full message that uses the attribute name so I don't have to change all my validations to make this change.